# Using Long Value In Android Databinding

Tags: android, android-databinding

I am trying to use `Long` value in `Android Databinding` but, just can't get it to work. This is everything I've tried

1: This worked fine. Until I started testing on pre-lollipop and I started experiencing crashes. I had to remove this `android:addTextChangedListener="@{outlet.onCapacityChange}"` from the XML

```
    Java
    @SerializedName("capacity")
    @Expose
    Long capacity
    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The capacity
     */
    @Bindable
    public Long getCapacity() {
        return capacity;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param capacity
     *     The capacity
     */
    public void setCapacity(Long capacity) {
        setAtomicCapacity(capacity);
        Log.e(TAG+"Capacity", "" + capacity);
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.capacity);
    }

    public void setAtomicCapacity(Long basic) {
        this.capacity = basic;
    }

    public TextWatcher onCapacityChange = new SimpleTextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(String newValue) {
            Log.e(TAG+"Capacity", newValue);
            setAtomicCapacity(Long.valueOf(newValue));
        }
    };

    XML
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/outletStockCapacity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:text='@{outlet.capacity != null ? String.valueOf(outlet.capacity) : ""}'
        android:addTextChangedListener="@{outlet.onCapacityChange}"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"/>
```

2: After changing all `android:addTextChangedListener="@{outlet.onCapacityChange}"` to `android:text="@={String.valueOf(outlet.capacity)}"` using `=` `Equal Operator` since two way binding is now provided by default.

```
    Java
    @SerializedName("capacity")
    @Expose
    Long capacity = 0L;
    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The capacity
     */
    @Bindable
    public Long getCapacity() {
        return capacity;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param capacity
     *     The capacity
     */
    public void setCapacity(Long capacity) {
        setAtomicCapacity(capacity);
        Log.e(TAG+"Capacity", "" + capacity);
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.capacity);
    }

    public void setAtomicCapacity(Long basic) {
        this.capacity = basic;
    }

    XML
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/outletStockCapacity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:text="@={String.valueOf(outlet.capacity)}"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"/>
```

The first was working fine on `Post Lollipop` but, not working on `Pre-Lollipop`. This is my SimpleTextWatcher

```
public abstract class SimpleTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        onTextChanged(s.toString());
    }

    public abstract void onTextChanged(String newValue);
}
```

My project wouldn't build because of this. I don't know why? I checked for null, initialized it and all. But, it wouldn't just build because of that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this `android:text="@={outlet.capacityAsString}"`, where capacityAsString is `String` (`ObservableField<String>`)
I dont think, you can use something like `String.valueOf(outlet.capacity)` for two way binding.

**EDITED**: Really, there is a way to use something like `android:text="@={outlet.capacityAsLong}"`, but you have to write custom  `@InverseBindingAdapter`:

```
public class MyEditTextBindingAdapters {

    @BindingConversion
    public static String longToStr(Long value) {
        return value != null ? String.valueOf(value) : "";
    }

    @InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "android:text", event = "android:textAttrChanged")
    public static Long captureLongValue(EditText view) {
        long value = 0;
        try {
            value = Long.parseLong(view.getText().toString());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

It works perfectly, but you need to set `android:inputType="number"` for your EditText.

Answer (score 1):

It is not that you cannot perform two-way binding with long value, but here problem is `android:text` will accept `String` value, although you are converting `long` to `String` but if you are performing two-way binding, direct value should be `String`.

Simplest solution for this would be, take `ObservableField<String>` in your model class, instead of long.